# Is there autopilot for player ship?

Tags: x-rebirth

Can i point on system map destination and just fly all way on autopilot?

I am not huge fan of space lanes, after i missed exit and flied 50 km back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update 2.0 (released 2014-05-20) Added autopilot to player ship.

Autopilot flies to mission or guide location.

It is useful for escort missions.

Answer (score 2):

You can order your Freighter to take you there by talking to the captain (Enter->2->2->"CO" button). Then he will wait for you to land, and fly there. Hands off :)

Comment: I tried it with my freighter, asked to take me to near zone. Freigter ignored highway and flied by straight line.

Comment: Yeah that happened to me too but I assumed it was distance related. Well its something, and you can go have a coffee while it flies you there (assuming longer distances involve using highways). Sorry, assumed you down voted.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, there is unfortunately no autopilot in this game.